# package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist cucumber

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to run my cucumber tests with maven and junit. When i use the cucumber keywords @given, @when etc., it is showing error as **package cucumber.api.java.en does not exist**. I tried with maven version 3.3.9 and below is my pom.xml. I don't know whether it is a dependency mismatch or anything else. Can any one help me in this.

**pom.xml:**

```
     <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>
                maven-compiler-plugin
            </artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <!-- <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration> -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Check your cucumber-java jar in maven dependencies, the package with the annotation code should be present in that. You might want to include cucumber-html in the dependency, though it has got nothing to with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try @When, @Given. Capitalization is important.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I am able to solve this issue by placing my stepdefs file in test folder under src.

Comment: @Stephen would you be willing to add your comment as an answer and accept it?  I made the same mistake -- I put the step definitions under src/main/java instead of src/test/java.

Answer (score 0):

Place your TestRunner.java class and the step definitions under src/test/java directory and feature files under src/test/resources directory

Comment: Thankyou @Aditya, I had an old Maven project which wasn't set up correctly and this helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I updated POM.XML with this and it's works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberBasic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```